# php processing multiple checkbox select with javascript

Tags: php, javascript, checkbox

I am creating a form with multiple checkboxes with the same name. I have included an option for the user to select the parent checkbox to check all the children. The javascript code below is used to select or deselect all check boxes.

```
function checkAll(field)
{
  i = 0;
  if(field[i].checked)
  {
    uncheckAll(field);
  }
  else
  {
    for (i = 0; i < field.length; i++)
      field[i].checked = true ;
  }
}

function uncheckAll(field)
{
  for (i = 0; i < field.length; i++)
  field[i].checked = false ;
}
```

Basically what I want to do is process the selections, when the form is submitted, by grabbing the children checkboxes that were selected using $_POST and do a database query, but in order for all the children checkboxes with the same name to show up in $_POST in an array, they need to have the square brackets attached to them, which unfortunately isn't supported by the javascript.

```
<div class ="county-select">
    <div><label for="franklin">Franklin County</label><input name="county[]" value="franklin" type="checkbox" class="noBorderIE" onClick="checkAll(document.frmEventExport.townF)" /></div>
    <div><label for="oxford">Oxford Hills</label><input name="county[]" value="oxford" type="checkbox" class="noBorderIE" onClick="checkAll(document.frmEventExport.townO)" />  </div>
    <div><label for="river-valley">River Valley</label><input name="county[]" value="river-valley" type="checkbox" class="noBorderIE" onClick="checkAll(document.frmEventExport.townR)" /></div>
    <div><label for="city">City</label><input name="county[]" value="city" type="checkbox" class="noBorderIE" onClick="checkAll(document.frmEventExport.townC)" /></div> 
  </div>
    </div>
<div class="town-select"> 
  <div id="Franklin-county">
    <label for="avon">Avon</label><input name="townF" value="avon" type="checkbox" class="noBorderIE" /><br/>
    <label for="CV">Carrabassett Valley</label><input name="townF" value="carrabassett valley" type="checkbox" class="noBorderIE" /><br/>
    <label for="carthage">Carthage</label><input name="townF" value="carthage" type="checkbox" class="noBorderIE" /><br/>
    <label for="chesterville">Chesterville</label><input name="townF" value="chesterville" type="checkbox" class="noBorderIE" /><br/>
    <label for="CP">Coplin Plantation</label><input name="townF" value="coplin plantation" type="checkbox" class="noBorderIE" /><br/>
    <label for="DP">Dallas Plantation</label><input name="townF" value="dallas plantation" type="checkbox" class="noBorderIE" /><br/>
    <label for="eustis">Eustis</label><input name="townF" value="eustis" type="checkbox" class="noBorderIE" /><br/>

    <label for="farmington">Farmington</label><input name="townF" value="farmington" type="checkbox" class="noBorderIE" /><br/>
    <label for="fayette">Fayette</label><input name="townF" value="fayette" type="checkbox" class="noBorderIE" /><br/>
    <label for="FT">Freeman township</label><input name="townF" value="freeman township" type="checkbox" class="noBorderIE" /><br/>
    <label for="industry">Industry</label><input name="townF" value="industry" type="checkbox" class="noBorderIE" /><br/>
    <label for="jay">Jay</label><input name="townF" value="jay" type="checkbox" class="noBorderIE" /><br/>
    <label for="kingfield">Kingfield</label><input name="townF" value="kingfield" type="checkbox" class="noBorderIE" /><br/>
    <label for="livermore">Livermore</label><input name="townF" value="livermore" type="checkbox" class="noBorderIE" /><br/>
    <label for="LF">Livermore Falls</label><input name="townF" value="livermore falls" type="checkbox" class="noBorderIE" /><br/>

    <label for="MT">Madrid township</label><input name="townF" value="madrid township" type="checkbox" class="noBorderIE" /><br/>
    <label for="MV">Mount Vernon</label><input name="townF" value="mount vernon" type="checkbox" class="noBorderIE" /><br/>
    <label for="NS">New Sharon</label><input name="townF" value="new sharon" type="checkbox" class="noBorderIE" /><br/>
    <label for="NV">New Vineyard</label><input name="townF" value="new vineyard" type="checkbox" class="noBorderIE" /><br/>
    <label for="PT">Perkins township</label><input name="townF" value="perkins township" type="checkbox" class="noBorderIE" /><br/>
    <label for="phillips">Phillips</label><input name="townF" value="phillips" type="checkbox" class="noBorderIE" /><br/>
    <label for="rangeley">Rangeley</label><input name="townF" value="rangeley" type="checkbox" class="noBorderIE" /><br/>
    <label for="RP">Rangeley Plantation</label><input name="townF" value="rangeley plantation" type="checkbox" class="noBorderIE" /><br/>

    <label for="readfield">Readfield</label><input name="townF" value="readfield" type="checkbox" class="noBorderIE" /><br/>
    <label for="SRP">Sandy River Plantation</label><input name="townF" value="sandy river plantation" type="checkbox" class="noBorderIE" /><br/>
    <label for="strong">Strong</label><input name="townF" value="strong" type="checkbox" class="noBorderIE" /><br/>
    <label for="temple">Temple</label><input name="townF" value="temple" type="checkbox" class="noBorderIE" /><br/>
    <label for="vienna">Vienna</label><input name="townF" value="vienna" type="checkbox" class="noBorderIE" /><br/>
    <label for="weld">Weld</label><input name="townF" value="weld" type="checkbox" class="noBorderIE" /><br/>
    <label for="wilton">Wilton</label><input name="townF" value="wilton" type="checkbox" class="noBorderIE" /><br/>

  </div>
```

Does anyone know a way around this?? ..sorry for the length, btw

Comment: So your question is how to get the values that are selected ? But in function that your javascript keeps working ?

Comment: apart of your question, have you considered using jquery?

Comment: jQuery isn't really necessary if this is all he needs, it's pretty simple JavaScript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the brackets in Javascript as long as you put it in a string.  I tested this out below with your code and it looks like it should work how you need it.

**JavaScript Code:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function checkAll(parent, field)
{
    var children = document.getElementsByName(field);
    var newValue = parent.checked;
    for (i = 0; i < children.length; i++){
        children[i].checked = newValue;
    }
}
</script>
```

**HTML Content Snippet:**

```
<div class ="county-select">
  <div><label for="franklin">Franklin County</label><input name="county[]" value="franklin" type="checkbox" class="noBorderIE" onChange="checkAll(this, 'townF[]')" /></div>
  <div><label for="oxford">Oxford Hills</label><input name="county[]" value="oxford" type="checkbox" class="noBorderIE" onChange="checkAll(this, 'townO[]')" />  </div>
  <div><label for="river-valley">River Valley</label><input name="county[]" value="river-valley" type="checkbox" class="noBorderIE" onChange="checkAll(this, 'townR[]')" /></div>
  <div><label for="city">City</label><input name="county[]" value="city" type="checkbox" class="noBorderIE" onChange="checkAll(this, 'townC[]')" /></div> 
</div>
<div class="town-select">
    <div id="Franklin-county">
    <label for="avon">Avon</label><input name="townF[]" value="avon" type="checkbox" class="noBorderIE" /><br/>
    <label for="CV">Carrabassett Valley</label><input name="townF[]" value="carrabassett valley" type="checkbox" class="noBorderIE" /><br/>
    <label for="carthage">Carthage</label><input name="townF[]" value="carthage" type="checkbox" class="noBorderIE" /><br/>
    <label for="chesterville">Chesterville</label><input name="townF[]" value="chesterville" type="checkbox" class="noBorderIE" /><br/>
    <label for="CP">Coplin Plantation</label><input name="townF[]" value="coplin plantation" type="checkbox" class="noBorderIE" /><br/>
    <label for="DP">Dallas Plantation</label><input name="townF[]" value="dallas plantation" type="checkbox" class="noBorderIE" /><br/>
    <label for="eustis">Eustis</label><input name="townF[]" value="eustis" type="checkbox" class="noBorderIE" /><br/>
  </div>
</div>
```